# Crashlytics not updating Android version code in IntelliJ

Tags: android, scala, intellij-idea, sbt, crashlytics

I'm using the Crashlytics plugin version 1.8.0, and IntelliJ CE 13.1.4 on OSX 10.9.4.

I'm also using Scala, and using the `sbt` build system externally instead of IntelliJ's `Make`.

The `crashlytics-build.properties` file only updates to the latest version code & name from the AndroidManifest.xml upon starting/restarting IntelliJ.

I suspect the normal build process for Java kicks the Crashlytics plugin into doing this, but I'm not sure where or what that looks like - is it something that could be replicated and inserted into my own sbt build script?

Otherwise, it's easy to accidentally send a new build using the old version info.

Comment: Try moving to Fabric https://dev.twitter.com/fabric/android/integrating